# Replace the "click" to "onload"

Tags: javascript, click, onload

How can I replace the "click" in this code to click when the page is load "onload"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function() {
    request();
    return false;
});

$("#website-form input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        request();
        return false;
    }
});
```

});

I try to do this:

```
$("#submit").trigger('click')(function() {
```

But I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Please help

Comment: How about `$(function(){ $("#website-form").submit() });`

Answer (score 0):

`$("#submit").trigger('click')(function() {` is an invalid statement. `$("#submit").trigger('click')` returns a jQuery object referencing the `#submit` element, it is not a function that is the reason for the error.

You need only `$("#submit").trigger('click')` to manually trigger the click handler

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#submit").trigger('click')
```

Comment: how? i try allready like this: $("#submit").trigger('click').click(function() {

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
$(function(){ $("#website-form").submit() });
```

or

```
$(function(){ request() });
```

Comment: the form code is: 

   

         <form id="website-form">
        <div class="input-append control-group">
        <input class="input" name="Website[domain]" id="domain" value="<?php echo $first_line ?> " type="text">
        <button class="btn" id="submit" type="button"><?php echo Yii::t("app", "data") ?></button>
    </form>
maybe that will halp..

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submit").click();
}
```